# Как подключить к node.js "внешнюю" библиотеку из Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-maps-api, google-maps

Пытаюсь получить из Google Maps API большой набор координат для дальнейшей обработки. Обращаюсь к библиотеке geometry из Google Maps Javascript API
Использую node.js, поскольку через обычный браузер получить (а потом обработать) массив из 1,25M элементов с координатами — нереально.
Пытаюсь подключить Geometry через require

```
var libGetter = require('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=someKey&libraries=geometry');
```

и получаю ошибку

> Error: Cannot find module 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=someKey&libraries=geometry'

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы node.js сервер смог воспользоваться библиотекой geometry? Как её добавить?
Да, есть Node.js Client for Google Maps Services, но библиотеки Geometry там нет и нужного мне метода computeOffset(), увы, тоже. Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если этот метод там есть, и я его проморгал.

Comment: "нет и нужного мне метода computeOffset() `computeOffset()`" -> см. https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib#geolibcomputedestinationpointstart-distance-bearing-radiusoptional

Comment: Посмотрел модуль. Это действительно отличный заменитель computeOffset. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодарю Yaant за ответ на вопрос.
Как вариант, можно использовать модуль geolib, метод

```
computeDestinationPoint(start, distance, bearing, radius(optional))
```

где start - объект LatLng.

[Ссылка на страницу модуля](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib)

Опыт показал, что метод computeDestinationPoint из Geolib и метод computeOffset из библиотеки geometry в Google Maps API при одинаковых входных данных иногда (но не всегда) выдают разные координаты. Разница между ними навскидку не более 10-15 см. Для моих задач это более чем допустимо; устроит ли вас - смотрите сами.